# Save a certificate for later signing

Tags: openssl

With OpenSSL, is it possible to generate, serialize and save a certificate to a file without signing it (and I mean a certificate, not a CSR) and then load the saved DER or PEM, deserialize and sign it, perhaps on another machine?

I have not been able to find a way to create an unsigned certificate with openssl over the command line, but I've put together a program to do it (X509_new() and fill in the appropriate data). However the problem is if I don't sign the certificate (with X509_sign()) before serializing it, deserialization fails with encoding errors.

Comment: This sounds like an XY Problem. (http://xyproblem.info) What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The certificate is for a public key the private part of which is in a module that only exposes it through a limited API, such as for signing a hash. So I was trying to get away without having to create a CSR, which requires access to the private key. The alternative as I see it is to pack up all the data that goes into the certificate myself and send it over, but I was hoping to use openssl for serializing / deserializing. Am I on the wrong path?

Comment: Yes. Use a CSR. HSMs usually allow for that and there should be customer support for any specific HSM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through OpenSSL release 1.0.2, the TBS portion of a certificate is field `x509->cert_info` with type `X509_CINF` which is a typedef for `struct x509_cinf_st`. Following the usual pattern you can ser/deser this with `{i2d,d2i}_X509_CINF_*` . Remember X.509 has an AlgorithmIdentifier for the signature (OpenSSL type `X509_ALGOR`) both inside the TBS and outside, so you'll need to set the inside field to some valid value even if it isn't the value that will actually be used when signing.

In 1.1.0 the X509 structure is made opaque (along with many others), and there is no API to access this piece. But if you cheat a little and use `crypto/include/internal/x509_int.h` to get it, the typedef and declarations for the i2d/d2i routines are still officially externalized. This is inconsistent, and it wouldn't surprise me if it changes in the future.

Answer (score 1):

> ... serialize and save a certificate to a file without signing it (and I mean a certificate, not a CSR) ... create an unsigned certificate

There is no such thing as an unsigned certificate. If it is not signed then it is not a certificate.

> However the problem is if I don't sign the certificate (with X509_sign()) before serializing it, deserialization fails with encoding errors.

I have no idea what kind of serialization and deserialization you've tried (no code given).

But what you essentially ask is to freeze all data structures related to the current state of the signing process before doing the actual signing and thaw these again on another machine to continue the signing. In theory this should be possible since one could migrate whole processes or virtual machines between systems so the question is mainly how to make the freezing minimal.

OpenSSL does not have an explicit API for this, because there was no use case so far which required it to have such an API. And I don't see a real use case from your question either because you could simply use the CSR and all the information you need to sign and do the whole processes on the other machine. This looks more like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're a bit confused by the terms.  A certificate is a document that has been signed by a Certificate Authority (CA) -- if it's not signed, it's not a certificate.  A Certificate Signing Request (CSR) is a document to be signed, plus the metadata needed for signing. Generally speaking, and specifically when you're dealing with OpenSSL, the "document" to be signed is a public key.

The steps you normally take with OpenSSL are these:

1. Use `openssl genpkey` to generate a public/private key pair.
2. Collect metadata regarding key usage, distinguished name, etc.
3. Use `openssl req` to format the metadata and public key according to the structure for Certificate Signing Requests; the PKCS#10 format is an ASN.1 encoded document that is used when generating X.509 certificate requests.  If you're going to transmit this CSR data via email or in a text file, it's often  Base64 encoded.
4. Send the CSR to the CA for signing.
5. Receive the signed certificate from the CA.

Also note that you would not normally use OpenSSL to sign the CSR yourself.  You would only do this if you had a strong reason for a self-signed certificate (maybe setting up your own private VPN.)  Self-signed certificates prove nothing to anyone but you because they are not signed by a trusted root CA; therefore they are not trusted by browsers or other computers.

What you describe is possible by storing the CSR.  Again, if it's not signed, it can't be a certificate.

Comment: I don't think the Q is confused or unclear at all; OP does want to create the cert themself, even though that is unusual.